# Consultation about cast and max date in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

I have this table. The **TDate is a string (not a date).**

```
MEN    
===

id       |   Name       |      TDate    
1        |   aa         |      01.05.2015    
2        |   bb         |      05.05.2015    
3        |   cc         |      07.01.2015    
4        |   dd         |      04.04.2015
```

I need to get the max date:

```
2        |   bb           |       05.05.2015
```

How can I do this in MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert `tdate` to an actual date, sort by it, and limit the query to a single row:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     men
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(tdate, '%d.%m.%Y') DESC
LIMIT    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix your data to store the value as a date:

```
alter table t
    add column newTdate date;

update t
    set newTdate = str_to_date(Tdate, '%d.%m.%Y');

alter table t
     drop column Tdate;

alter tabe t
     change column newTdate Tdate;
```

Then your code will work and your database will be fixed.